# Mixing Shofar Sounds

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar

This year we had multiple minyanim, some of which started at the same time. They all had shofar blown outside of the building. This created the possibility that people from one minyan might hear the shofar blown from another minyan. Could these "other" sounds corrupt the intended sounds?

If the one who calls the sounds says "sh'varim" and just as the one who blows finishes the sh'varim, a blower from another minyan sounds a t'ruah, does the one who listens "hear" the combination sound even though "his" blower only intended the sh'varim?

Comment: This is a huge problem! See OC 590:8. Most places I know of staggered minyan start times to avoid this sort of issue

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume that there was some staggering of times (I davened at a different minyan) but I'm just trying to understand issues of intent and the like on a theoretical basis.

Comment: The issue isn't just what you are asking that maybe you end up with a shvarim-truah. It's if you hear a shvarim or truah after your shvarim or truah or shvarim-truah, you messed up the line and have to go back to the opening tekia. The rule is you always must hear 3 sets of exactly tekia-["terua"]-tekia in that order.

Comment: @DoubleAA and would any sound that I can hear count as part of the sounds that I am intending to hear?

Comment: Only if the blower and blowee intend to fulfill the blowee's obligation. (It's commonly assumed that one blowing at a public service intends to fulfill anyone in the community's obligation. I don't know how that applies to multiple minyanim in the same shul.)

Comment: @DoubleAA wouldn't the blowee intend to only fulfill his obligation with his own minyan?

Comment: @Heshy That's not up to me to decide

Comment: @DoubleAA but I'd think that's the stam daas for someone who hasn't really thought about it

Comment: @Heshy that's plausible at least in normal enough cases but I don't know why it matters here